# "Качаться на качелях" - тавтология?

Tags: употребление-слов

Я опять с качелями.

Можно как-то другими словами обозначить процесс использования качелей по прямому назначению, чтобы избежать тавтологии? Я не нашла. Или это слово уже "живет" само по себе, и тавтологии нет? На качелях можно посидеть, постоять и даже повисеть при желании.

В словаре Даля есть интересные  слова (опять же в статье "качать"):  "Качуляться, качулить, -ся новг. качать, -ся на качелях."  Но я таких никогда не слышала.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так получилось, что в русском языке, ни у слова "качаться", ни у слова "качели", нет нематерного синонима. "Кататься на качелях", по мне так, как раз пример того как, в попытке избежать того, что в школе называли ошибкой, образованные люди язык коверкают. Как бы мы не выпендривались, но катаются по ровной поверхности,  а качаются по параболе. Поэтому детвора летом качается на качелях, а зимой катается на катках.

Вообще в речи тавтологической ошибкой воспринимается,  только повторение одного и того же слова, в тех случаях, когда избежать повтора возможно, и то, как правило для ощущения ошибки нужно более двух однокоренных слов с одинаковым смыслом. *Пошёл Вася в лес, набрал Василий грибов, и сделал Васятка грибы с картошкой.*

В общем, если есть тавтология, но нет плеоназма, речь это ничуть не портит. *Вася почистил **грибы** и сделал **грибной суп. Суп** получился отменный.*

Answer (score 2):

Согласна, тавтологии не чувствуется. А как иначе сказать? Ну, разве что "кататься", но это не совсем точно.
К тому же, на качелях можно не только качаться, но и, например, просто сидеть. Не качаясь.
Так что все нормально.

Answer (score 1):

Можно кататься на качелях. Хотя "качать" - от "катать, качу". Но вид другой. По-моему, и в "качаться на качелях" тавтология  не чувствуется,по крайней мере, не бросается в глаза,а иногда даже звучит как фигура речи, милый каламбурчик: Покачалась на качелях, искупалася в купели, заметелила в метель.

Answer (score 1):

Качаться - описание возвратно-поступательного движения. Кто качается - периодически возвращается в исходную точку пространства - это обязательное условие процесса раскачивания.
Кататься - перемещение в пространстве из точки А в точку Б. Возврат в исходную точку при катании допустим, но не является обязательным условием процесса катания.

Comment: >>перемещение в пространстве из точки А в точку Б

Это больше подходит к глаголу **катИться**, а **катАться** имеет все же иной оттенок: либо меняющиеся (неопределенное) направление, либо неоднократность действия.

Answer (score 1):

Катайтесь на карусели!

==============================================

Любишь кататься - катись к чертовой матери! А. Кнышев